# numpy second derivative of a ndimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of simulation data where I would like to find the lowest slope in n dimensions. The spacing of the data is constant along each dimension, but not all the same (I could change that for the sake of simplicity).

I can live with some numerical inaccuracy, especially towards the edges. I would heavily prefer not to generate a spline and use that derivative; just on the raw values would be sufficient.

It is possible to calculate the first derivative with `numpy` using the `numpy.gradient()` function.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(30,50,40,20)
first_derivative = np.gradient(data)
# second_derivative = ??? <--- there be kudos (:
```

---

This is a comment regarding laplace versus the hessian matrix; this is no more a question but is meant to help understanding of future readers.

I use as a testcase a 2D function to determine the 'flattest' area below a threshold. The following pictures show the difference in results between using the minimum of `second_derivative_abs = np.abs(laplace(data))` and the minimum of the following:

```
second_derivative_abs = np.zeros(data.shape)
hess = hessian(data)
# based on the function description; would [-1] be more appropriate? 
for i in hess[0]: # calculate a norm
    for j in i[0]:
        second_derivative_abs += j*j
```

The color scale depicts the functions values, the arrows depict the first derivative (gradient), the red dot the point closest to zero and the red line the threshold.

The generator function for the data was `( 1-np.exp(-10*xi**2 - yi**2) )/100.0` with xi, yi being generated with `np.meshgrid`.

Laplace:

[image: laplace solution]

Hessian:

[image: hessian solution]

Comment: I wonder; I am only interested in the magnitude of slope, not so much the directions. Might it be sufficient if I calculate the gradient on the sum of the absolute first derivative list entries? `second_derivative = np.gradient(sum([df*df for d in first_derivative]))` (with `sum` conserving the shape for the sake of argument)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you want now. You just want to get the flattest region, or whatever "flattest" means in N dimensions. I'd try not to use some second derivative at all, but calculate the absolute gradient at all points (sum over the squares of the first dimension of the result of `np.gradient`, like you said in your comment), and then find the threshold region from that, and find the minimum inside the threshold region (if you function is sufficiently complicated, finding global minima can be really hard). I'll try around a bit and post another answer if I find something.

Comment: @Carsten The sum of all gradients will not yield the flattest area; in this test case picture it would yield the center of the 2d gaussian. this is by no means the flattest area. Therefore I think it needs to be done with the propper 2nd derivative instead of the first one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The second derivatives are given by the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix). Here is a Python  implementation for ND arrays, that consists in applying the `np.gradient` twice and storing the output appropriately,

```
import numpy as np

def hessian(x):
    """
    Calculate the hessian matrix with finite differences
    Parameters:
       - x : ndarray
    Returns:
       an array of shape (x.dim, x.ndim) + x.shape
       where the array[i, j, ...] corresponds to the second derivative x_ij
    """
    x_grad = np.gradient(x) 
    hessian = np.empty((x.ndim, x.ndim) + x.shape, dtype=x.dtype) 
    for k, grad_k in enumerate(x_grad):
        # iterate over dimensions
        # apply gradient again to every component of the first derivative.
        tmp_grad = np.gradient(grad_k) 
        for l, grad_kl in enumerate(tmp_grad):
            hessian[k, l, :, :] = grad_kl
    return hessian

x = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100)
hessian(x)
```

Note that if you are only interested in the magnitude of the second derivatives, you could use the [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) implemented by  [`scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace.html#scipy-ndimage-filters-laplace), which is the trace (sum of diagonal elements) of the Hessian matrix.

Taking the smallest element of the the Hessian matrix could be used to estimate the lowest slope in any spatial direction.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with both proposed solutions on a 2D testcase (I like to look at things). When saying slope, I mean the least in all directions; basically the locally most flat area I can find. Looks promising so far, but still have some testing to do (:

Comment: I do not have the space to post the 2D testcase without polluting the question; difference in results between laplace and hessian seems to be that they yield different points. I evaluate either the minimum of the laplace or the sum of squares along `x.dim, x.ndim` for the hessian. To my understanding, the latter takes mixed derivatives into account and thus should be more accurate for my purpose?

Comment: I added pictures of a 2d testcase for laplace and hessian. While I think both algorithms do a good job, I think I will prefer the hessian and extend it to variable stepwidths; also as discussed it does the job more correct. Edit: I just saw your edit on your answer; could you therefore please review my pictures / code and tell me if I am really doing it right (:

Comment: For an already implemented algorithm for the Hessian matrix calculation, have a look at the `Numdifftools` project: https://pypi.org/project/numdifftools/

Answer (score 6):

Slopes, Hessians and Laplacians are related, but are 3 different things.
Start with 2d: a function( x, y ) of 2 variables, e.g. a height map of a range of hills,

- slopes aka gradients are direction vectors, a direction and length at each point `x y`.
  This can be given by 2 numbers `dx dy` in cartesian coordinates,
  or an angle θ and length `sqrt( dx^2 + dy^2 )` in polar coordinates.
  Over a whole range of hills, we get a
  [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field).
- Hessians describe curvature near `x y`, e.g. a paraboloid or a saddle,
  with 4 numbers: `dxx dxy dyx dyy`.
- a Laplacian is 1 number, `dxx + dyy`, at each point `x y`.
  Over a range of hills, we get a
  [scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field).
  (Functions or hills with [Laplacian = 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_equation)
  are particularly smooth.)

Slopes are linear fits and Hessians quadratic fits, for tiny steps `h` near a point `xy`:

```
f(xy + h)  ~  f(xy)
        +  slope . h    -- dot product, linear in both slope and h
        +  h' H h / 2   -- quadratic in h
```

Here `xy`, `slope` and `h` are vectors of 2 numbers,
and `H` is a matrix of 4 numbers `dxx dxy dyx dyy`.

N-d is similar: slopes are direction vectors of N numbers,
Hessians are matrices of N^2 numbers, and Laplacians 1 number, at each point.

(You might find better answers over on
[math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[gradient]+hessian) .)

Answer (score 4):

You can see the Hessian Matrix as a gradient of gradient, where you apply gradient a second time for each component of the first gradient calculated here is a wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) definig Hessian matrix and you can see clearly that is a gradient of gradient, here is a python implementation defining gradient then hessian :

```
import numpy as np
#Gradient Function
def gradient_f(x, f):
  assert (x.shape[0] >= x.shape[1]), "the vector should be a column vector"
  x = x.astype(float)
  N = x.shape[0]
  gradient = []
  for i in range(N):
    eps = abs(x[i]) *  np.finfo(np.float32).eps 
    xx0 = 1. * x[i]
    f0 = f(x)
    x[i] = x[i] + eps
    f1 = f(x)
    gradient.append(np.asscalar(np.array([f1 - f0]))/eps)
    x[i] = xx0
  return np.array(gradient).reshape(x.shape)

#Hessian Matrix
def hessian (x, the_func):
  N = x.shape[0]
  hessian = np.zeros((N,N)) 
  gd_0 = gradient_f( x, the_func)
  eps = np.linalg.norm(gd_0) * np.finfo(np.float32).eps 
  for i in range(N):
    xx0 = 1.*x[i]
    x[i] = xx0 + eps
    gd_1 =  gradient_f(x, the_func)
    hessian[:,i] = ((gd_1 - gd_0)/eps).reshape(x.shape[0])
    x[i] =xx0
  return hessian
```

As a test, the Hessian matrix of (x^2 + y^2) is **2 * I_2** where I_2 is the identity matrix of dimension 2

Comment: I think the Hessian is the Jacobian of the gradient, not the gradient of the gradient. See wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix)

Comment: @Srikiran Its somewhat a matter of semantics. The Jacobian is effectively just a gradient defined for vector valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
hessians = np.asarray(np.gradient(np.gradient(f(X, Y))))
hessians[1:]
```

Worked for 3-d function f.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sympy hessian (second derivative matrix) or jacobian (first derivative)? Try this, for your function:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()

x_i,y_i = sp.symbols("x_i,y_i")
f = sp.Function("f")(x_i,y_i)
f = (1 - sp.exp(-10*x_i**2-y_i**2))/100
# Jacobian matrix - first derivative
J = sp.Matrix([f]).jacobian([x_i,y_i])
J
# Hessian matrix - second derivative
H = sp.hessian(f, (x_i, y_i))
H
```

It produces a Hessian:
[image]